# ListBox mnemonic default behaviour

Tags: vb.net

I use 3rd party `listbox` component and this component uses mnemonic which i am not able to disable so every time i have to make lot of conversions for ampersands (&). Question is how normal win forms `listbox` trade mnemonics by default. Would chars will be displayed in list as they came in without any mnemonic? For instance when input string is:

```
&&a
```

Will it be trade and shown as it is?

Comment: need more information, what is the 3rd party listbox called? also please post your code as it will have clues to fix your problem.

Comment: The question that you posted on this topic a few hours ago was put on hold because it was "unclear what you're asking". This version doesn't seem to be any clearer. Can you please explain what you are talking about? Id "Mnemonic" a special term used by the 3rd party vendor of the control you are using?

Comment: @Blackwood: No, a mnemonic is a typical Windows Forms term for a shortcut on an Alt+key combination. It's the ampersand in front of a character which then determines the additional key to press with Alt.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether a standard `ListBox` behaves the same way as your custom control.  Why not just test a standard `ListBox` and see for yourself?

Comment: I am asking about ListBox from Windows Forms.